# What is a pain response when the feeling of pain isn't there?

Tags: pain, joints, reflex-impulse

**Is there a term and definition for when the body reacts to pain you can't consciously feel?** To be more descriptive, *it's a reflex to pain,* like pulling back from a hot stove and coddling the finger you touched it with, although you *don't feel any pain.*

Less importantly, but more broadly speaking, *what is a reaction to what would be pain, though pain isn't felt by the person?*

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour)  and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Please edit your question to remove the personalised info in order to comply with site guidelines and try to make clear what you mean with pain response when there is no feeling of pain.

Comment: I edited it, I thought that it would help, that's why I added it in the first place. Thanks! I'm going through the tour and help pages now.

Comment: Thx for the edit. But: Hm, I'm still struggling to comprehend. Do you mean something like autonomous reflex, like touching something hot and retracting your finger immediately before you consciously realised it was hot? Or is that touching a hot plate, voluntarily lifting the finger and caring for it (you *know* it will be bad) although there is no pain felt at all?

Comment: It's like the first example you gave, an autonomous reflex. When I injure myself I always end up nursing it the moment right after I hurt it. It takes tremendous willpower or diverted focus to not do that right away.The strange part is the reflex when I can't feel that there is pain.

Comment: I edited your question to make it not such an obvious request for personal medical advice, but it's still completely unclear what you're asking so I voted to close on that basis. If you can clarify what you're asking, I'll retract.

Comment: That's fine and thanks Carey, I guess I'll restructure the whole thing to make the question obvious. The time has past for me needing the answer, the original health problem is gone now :)

Comment: There, I restructured and simplified the text to bring out the questions I was trying to ask. I have a bad habit of over-explaining and including too much context when asking long-winded questions. Thanks for helping me Carey, this is one reason why I like StackExchange :)

Comment: I think the question as it is right now is perfectly fine. Thanks for the edits.